# How to create a graph window in java

Tags: java, netbeans, graph, jfreechart

I'm using this code

```
private void botaoGrafADMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    try {
        boolean[] b=new boolean[8];
        if (Caixa9.isSelected()) b[0]=true; else b[0]=false;
        if (Caixa11.isSelected()) b[1]=true; else b[1]=false;
        if (Caixa10.isSelected()) b[2]=true; else b[2]=false;
        if (Caixa12.isSelected()) b[3]=true; else b[3]=false;
        b[4]=false;b[5]=false;b[6]=false;b[7]=false;
        final LineChartDemo1 demo = new LineChartDemo1("Leitura A/D",b,"outad.txt",4);
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Comunicacao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }       
}
```

to call an graph interface. But, when I do this, every time I call the graph, it generates on new window and, if I close on of these windows, the whole program is closed. 
I'd want to know what am I doing wrong. How Can I avoid this (I would post a printscreen, but, as new user, I can't, it is on https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JLxQ.png I think

Edit: Image
[image]

Answer (score 1):

JFrame has a default close operation (i.e. what happens when you close the window using your window manager) of EXIT_ON_CLOSE. Use [JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) to set a different value.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the class `LineChartDemo1` is, but you could probably set it as the content of a `JDialog` and call `setDefaultCloseOperation (JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)` on each dialog. This way, when the user closes the dialog, only that window will close, the others will remain open.

Comment: I just ran the code in a different JFrame so that when I close this, the program still running. Then, I used the

    public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent evt){
        if(evt.getWindow() == this){
        dispose();
        }
    }

not to close at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new netbeans JFrame and made reference to it like this:

```
InterfaceGrafico minhaInterface = new InterfaceGrafico("Leitura I/O",b,"outio.txt",8);
```

where the arguments where the same to generate the graph. In this "InterfaceGrafico" class:

```
public InterfaceGrafico(final String title,boolean[] b, String nomeArquivo, int col) {
try {
        initComponents();
        final LineChartDemo1 demo = new LineChartDemo1("Leitura I/O", b, "outio.txt", 8);
        demo.pack();
        RefineryUtilities.centerFrameOnScreen(demo);
        demo.setVisible(true);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(InterfaceGrafico.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

}

That means, I just shifted the code to another JFrame. I also commented the public void run method . Now I can close each graph generated without closing the whole application and the other generated graphs. In the "LineChart1" class, I added this

```
public void windowClosing(final WindowEvent evt){
    if(evt.getWindow() == this){
    dispose();
    }
}
```